# How to read, group and agg large flat file into pandas using chunk

Tags: python, pandas, chunking

I have a large file I'm trying to read into pandas.  I can group and agg the data but need to read it in chunks due to memory constraints.  I would like one final data frame of the grouped data shown below.  I've never ran by chunking before so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
mc = pd.read_csv('C:\\final2019new_paired.csv', chunksize=100000)

chunk_list = []

for chunk in mc:

    group = chunk.groupby(['anti_theft_code', 'atfault',  'BIlmt','CLded', 'CMded',  'cnty', 'componly'
                           , 'CREDIT_MODEL_CODE', 'DRIVER_AGE', 'DS_AB', 'DS_AD', 'DS_AK', 'DS_AT', 'DS_CH', 'DS_DD'
                           , 'DS_DE', 'DS_DF', 'DS_FP', 'DS_FQ', 'ds_gd', 'DS_IP', 'DS_KS', 'DS_LB', 'DS_LY', 'DS_MC'
                           , 'DS_ME', 'DS_ML', 'DS_MM', 'DS_MO', 'DS_MP', 'DS_MR', 'DS_MT', 'DS_MV', 'DS_PD', 'DS_PF'
                           , 'DS_PN', 'DS_PY', 'DS_RP', 'DS_SB', 'DS_SF', 'DS_SP', 'DS_ST', 'DS_TP', 'DS_TR', 'effyear'
                           , 'FIN_RESP_CD', 'majorvio', 'MARITAL_STATUS', 'minorvio', 'mpcnt',  'MPded', 'MPlmt', 'MVEH_CC'
                           , 'mveh_pkg_typ_cd', 'payplan', 'PDlmt', 'prdtype', 'product', 'RATING_CLASS_CODE', 'score'
                           , 'SD_AB', 'SD_SB', 'SD_TP', 'SD_TR', 'ST_AD', 'ST_AI', 'ST_CI', 'ST_DD', 'ST_DF', 'ST_MF'
                           , 'ST_MI', 'ST_MS', 'ST_RC', 'ST_RI', 'state', 'stored_locked_ind', 'term', 'terr'
                           , 'TOTL_YRS_LCNS_CNT', 'unit_drv_exp', 'units', 'unitval', 'unitzip', 'v_age', 'yrs_owned']
                 ).agg({'bi_cnt': 'sum', 'bi_eu':'sum', 'bi_earned': 'sum', 'bi_incrd': 'sum', 'bi_lae': 'sum'
                        , 'BI_prm': 'sum'
                        , 'cl_cnt': 'sum', 'cl_incrd': 'sum','coll_earned': 'sum', 'coll_eu':'sum', 'coll_if':'sum'
                        , 'cl_lae':'sum','cm_cnt':'sum', 'cm_incrd':'sum', 'cm_lae':'sum', 'CM_prm':'sum', 'cmt_cnt':'sum'
                        , 'cmt_incrd':'sum', 'cmt_lae':'sum', 'comp_earned':'sum', 'comp_if':'sum', 'mp_earned':'sum'
                        , 'mp_eu':'sum', 'mp_cnt':'sum','mp_incrd':'sum', 'mp_lae':'sum', 'MP_prm':'sum', 'pd_cnt':'sum'
                        , 'pd_earned':'sum', 'pd_eu':'sum', 'pd_if':'sum', 'pd_lae':'sum', 'PD_prm':'sum', 'um_cnt':'sum'
                        , 'um_earned':'sum', 'um_eu':'sum', 'um_if':'sum', 'um_incrd':'sum', 'um_lae':'sum'
                        , 'totalep':'sum'}).reset_index()

    chunk_list.append(group)


mc_raw = pd.concat(chunk_list)
```

I just get an empty list.

Can anyone see where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: is the variable `chunk` correct during the loop process?

Comment: no.  it seems there is no data coming out of the chunks.

Comment: try a much smaller `chunksize`, like 1000